# Hide directory in source code

Tags: joomla, hide

Actually my question is How is folder path hidden ? Firstly I am using Joomla.

I found a website 4 months ago, so i don't remember name of the website which is Joomla site. They hide their folder path.

Between to head> sth. head(tags). If you look at source code, you can see this part. And then this part include template name.
For example:

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://www.site.com/templates/template_name/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

So we can learn to what the name of the template. But they hide this part. When i looked this part(http://www.site.com/templates/template_name/css), i can see only /style.css.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need two things to accomplish that.

1. A (system) plugin, that changes every template related URL to the 'official' format, eg.

   ```
   $url = str_replace('/templates/template_name/css/', '/style/', $url;
   ```
2. An .htaccess redirect reverting the change.

   ```
   RewriteRule ^style/(.*)$ templates/template_name/css/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```

Comment: +1 Good answer without need of use a 3rd dev plugin, even if need write a (simple) new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want obscure template names, and a few modules and plugins from HTML source, the easy way is use a CSS and JS compressor like [jbetolo](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/site-performance/11545) or [RokBooster](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/site-performance/21233).

But keep in mind that you will make a bit more hader to find your template name, but still possible via other ways. Like some images if they are not compressed in HTML.